# How to get ssrs tablix limit

Tags: reporting-services

I've a report where I've added an column (no matter if it's populated or not).
When I try to upload report I get error

> An error has occurred. Try again later

My tablix has 78 column (I need to add 6 more column). There is a limit of tablix column?

Any idea what the issue may be?

This is log message:

```
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!7b!12/22/2020-16:55:38:: e ERROR: [c0y2u4py]: OData exception occurred: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices.SoapExceptionStrings.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed. at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName) at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary 2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices.SoapExceptionStrings.Keys.GetString(String key)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices.SoapExceptionStrings.get_MissingEndpoint()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.MissingEndpointException..ctor(Exception inner)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.CreateCatalogItem(String itemType, String name, String parent, Boolean overwrite, Byte[] definition, Property[] properties, Warning[]& warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapRS2010Proxy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateCatalogItem>b__0()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapAuthenticationHelper.ExecuteWithWindowsAuth[TReturn](SoapHttpClientProtocol soapClient, IPrincipal userPrincipal, Func'1 func)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapAuthenticationHelper.ExecuteWithCorrespondingAuthMechanism[TReturn](SoapHttpClientProtocol soapClient, IPrincipal userPrincipal, Func`1 func)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Services.SoapProxy.SoapRS2010Proxy.CreateCatalogItem(IPrincipal userPrincipal, String itemType, String name, String parentFolder, Boolean overwrite, Byte[] definition, Property[] properties)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemRepository.CreateReport(IPrincipal userPrincipal, String reportName, String parentFolder, Boolean overwrite, Byte[] definition, Property[] properties)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemRepository.Create(IPrincipal userPrincipal, CatalogItem catalogItem, CatalogItem& createdItem)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.ODataWebApi.V1.Controllers.CatalogItemsController.AddEntity(CatalogItem entity, CatalogItem& createdEntity)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.ODataWebApi.V1.Controllers.Reflection.EntitySetReflectionODataController`1.Post(ODataPath oDataPath, T value)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext().
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!e3!12/22/2020-16:55:38:: i INFO: [c0y2u4py]: 10.81.234.123: POST /api/v1.0/catalogitems - Response 500 - 0:00:11,4747865
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm going to ask what most people are thinking.. a report with 78 columns? Is this report really for someone to read or for something else to consume?

Comment: Is a user requirement. So what can I do if they wants all those information in a tablix?
But, with 78 columns upload works fine, 79 upload doesn't works